# newest post if else - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to have a conditional statement in a single post template loop where if the post is the most recent post (ie: newest post created) it will do **A** if it is not the do **B**.

I have searched everywhere, Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Run a custom query before main query to get the most recent post and compare their IDs:

```
// get 1 most recent post
$query_args = array(
'showposts'     => 1 // here you can add limit by categry etc
);
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
$query->the_post();
$recent_post_ID = $post->ID; // this is your most recent post ID

// this is your main loop
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

if ( $post->ID == $recent_post_ID ) { // check if IDs are equeal or not
// You are viewing most recent entry
} else {
// You are viewing older entry
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this too with WordPress' native function to retrieve the latest posts

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '1' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
$latest_post_id=$recent_posts[0]['ID'];

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    if ($post->ID == $latest_post_id) 
    {
        // code for newest post
    }
    else
    {
        // code for other than the newest post
    }
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```